# Powershell - Using ROBOCOPY to iterate the file paths and open this files in new folder

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to iterate the file path in the notepad (New_Test_File.txt) and by using the script I will open all these 5 files in a new file called "file_2"

**My "New_Test_File.txt" is -**

[image]

**My Expectation Output is -**

[image: My Expectation Output is]

**My script is -**

```
 $paths = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\JamesAlam\Desktop\New_Test_File.txt 
 foreach($path in $paths) {
 Write-Host $path
 ROBOCOPY /ZB /XO /R:3 /W:10 $path C:\Users\JamesAlam\Desktop\File_2
 }
```

I am a newbie in PowerShell and I am not sure how to use the ROBOCOPY method to copy these file paths and open them in the new folder. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use robocopy to copy only individual files? PowerShell has [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each robocopy action you should have, in your case - "source", "destination", and "file" (optional - arguments).

So... You will need to specify the source folder as the directory only, and the file name.

Try to run this, it should work:

```
$paths = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\JamesAlam\Desktop\New_Test_File.txt

 foreach($path in $paths) {
    $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($path)
    $fileName = Split-Path $path -leaf
 
 robocopy $directory C:\Users\JamesAlam\Desktop\File_2 $fileName
 }
```

Comment: Hi Bogner, the above code is working perfectly. Do you know how to get the log file when I run this code? I can use **Start-Transcript** method to get the lof file easily but problem is that we use Powershell version 2.0 and **Start-Transcript** doesn't support in the system. Is there any alternate way to get the log file? Thanks in advance.